# using fwrite() to write a struct to a file Error 688

Tags: c

error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘fwrite’
/usr/include/stdio.h:688: note: expected ‘const void * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘struct oseba’
make: *** [E1041080] Error 1

```
struct oseba{
char baza[100];
int telefonska;
char ime[10];
char priimek[20];
int dan;
int mesec;
int leto;
```

};

boys i need help! what is wrong?

---------------------------write-----------------------

```
FILE*file=fopen("fhfh.dat","wb");
if(file!=NULL)
{   fwrite(oseba1,sizeof(struct oseba),1,file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass a *pointer* to the structure. That is,

```
fwrite(&oseba1, sizeof(struct oseba), 1, file);
```

---

However beware that by writing `structs` into a binary file, it is highly probable that the file thus saved [will not be portable](http://c-faq.com/struct/io.html), e.g. you cannot share it even between 32-bit and 64-bit compilations of your program or from platform to another.

Comment: The last sentence is irrelevant to the question and would be better as a comment.

Comment: @immibis: That last sentence is clearly separated from the main body of the answer by a `<hr>`. It's an important caveat that anyone attempting to read & write `struct`s to a file should be aware of. So it deserves to be in the answer, not in a comment, since comments are "second-class citizens" on Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Well, it wasn't that much separated when immibis wrote that comment :D